# how to apply code first approach on server while creating new tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created models and used code first approach, so in my local in SSMS all tables created successfully.

Now I need to move to live server, but I am confused how can I apply migration over there on live server.

Should I copy sql file from local db and then run it on server DB

Or any other easy and best approach to do this.

Thanks

Comment: There is a mapping that exists between the database tables and the c# classes (model).  When you have a SSMS it is a MDF file.  When deatabae  islocal the connection string uses localdb.  When connected to a SSMS the connection string referencing the database on the server.  So do take a localDb and connect on the server all you need to do is attach the MDF file to the server and then change connection string and remove localDb and instead reference the database when MDF file is attached.

Comment: How did the tables get created in your local database? Was it perhaps by running the migrations? It's the same for production, update your connection strings and run the migrations against that. If you created the tables manually - that's not code first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You just need to change your `local connection string to a production one` and run the command below in package manager. Then all your not updated migration scripts will run on the production.

   PM> Update-Database

Use the followig to check if the database exists or not:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<YourDbContext>());
```

2. Another option is to generate a script from your dev SQL Management
   studio and run  it on production server

---

**Edit based on comment below:**

- check your sql connection string to production. Create a file in your disk with extension [Anyname]`.udl`
- open the file and on the tab `Provider` select: `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server` (if it is not selected)
- then click on `Connection` tab, then fill in the options and at the end click on Test Connection to see if you are connected successfully.
- Click OK.
  Open the file in Notepad and copy the connection string. Use that in your code to create the database and entities.

[image]

Comment: When i try this it is giving me error like unable to make connection with db

Comment: What was the exact error? Can you paste the connection string and how you are implementing the code?